# osx apply to enclosed items error

Tags: macos, permission

My network uses a magic triangle with windows server 2012 and osx Yosemite. I am migrating to a new osx server, this one using Sierra. So I copied all the user files from the old to the new server.

After copying, all the network user's permissions disappeared, so they won't be able to get at their files on the network. So I tried to restore their permissions one user at a time. I can change the ownership of a user's home directory. But when I try to use the "Make ___ the owner" or "Apply to enclosed items" I get the error:

The operation can't be completed
An unexpected error occurred (error code -8076).

How can I give my users their permissions back?

Comment: that GUI in the get info box has never worked as i expected for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I did it in terminal and it worked fine. I went to the correct directory and used:

`sudo chown -R user.name *`

That changed the permission recursively like it should.